# solve the inequality: $\displaystyle \ln|x^2 -3x+2|+\frac{2x-3}{x-2} \geq 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How can I solve the following inequality in the set of real numbers:

$\displaystyle \ln|x^2 -3x+2|+\frac{2x-3}{x-2} \geq 0$

Thanks in advace!

Comment: $x^2-3x+2=(x-2)(x-1)$ and $\frac{2x-3}{x-2} = 1+\frac{x-1}{x-2}$ might help

Comment: Are you sure that the inequality is porperly copied? Symbolic resolution of equations and inequalities when the unknown is inside and outside a logarythmic function is impossible, most of the times, at least. A computer plot shows that the solution is something like $\{x\leq 0.758\}\cup\{x>2\}$.

Comment: @ajotatxe, yes I am sure! It is an exercise..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$x^2-3x+2=(x-2)(x-1)$$
Consider the three intervals $I_1=]-\infty,1[$, $I_2=]1,2[$ and $I_3=]2,\infty[$ and $f(x)=\displaystyle \ln|x^2 -3x+2|+\frac{2x-3}{x-2}$

$f(x)=\displaystyle \ln(\pm(x^2 -3x+2))+\frac{2x-3}{x-2}$

$f'(x)=\displaystyle \frac{2x-3}{(x-2)(x-1)}-\frac{1}{(x-2)^2}=\frac{2x^2-8x+7}{(x-2)^2(x-1)}$

Then you calculate the roots, hence the variation of f and you can conclude that :

For $I_2$, no solution
For $I_3$, $I_3$ works
The problem is $I_1$ since you need to solve $f(x)=0$ and Wolfram said  there's no easy way to write it : [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln%7Cx%5E2%20-3x%2b2%7C%2b%282x-3%29/%28x-2%29%3E0)

Comment: Looks good, except not really pre-calc. +1.  Solution set is $(-\infty, \alpha] \cup (2, \infty)$, where $f(\alpha) = 0$.